# error TS2430: Interface 'WebGLRenderingContext' incorrectly extends interface 'WebGLRenderingContextBase'

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I run `tsc` it gives me this error output:

```js
../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15340,11): error TS2430: Interface 'WebGLRenderingContext' incorrectly extends interface 'WebGLRenderingContextBase'.
  Types of property 'getExtension' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (name: "ANGLE_instanced_arrays"): ANGLEInstancedArrays; (name: "EXT_blend_minmax"): EXTBlendMinMax; (name: "EXT_color_buffer_half_float"): EXTColorBufferHalfFloat; (name: "EXT_frag_depth"): EXTFragDepth; (name: "EXT_sRGB"): EXTsRGB; (name: "EXT_shader_texture_lod"): EXTShaderTextureLOD; (name: "EXT_texture_filter_...' is not assignable to type '{ (extensionName: "EXT_blend_minmax"): EXT_blend_minmax | null; (extensionName: "EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic"): EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic | null; (extensionName: "EXT_frag_depth"): EXT_frag_depth | null; (extensionName: "EXT_shader_texture_lod"): EXT_shader_texture_lod | null; (extensionName: "EXT_sRGB"): EX...'.
      Types of parameters 'name' and 'extensionName' are incompatible.
        Type '"OES_vertex_array_object"' is not assignable to type '"ANGLE_instanced_arrays"'.
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

`tsc` is version `Version 3.1.3`.

Here is my `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "pupp-tf-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Try to get environment set up to program using TypeScript, Puppeteer, and TensorFlow.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "xiaodeaux",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^0.1.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.0"
  }
}
```

The the only `.ts` file I have is empty. So this has nothing to do with the code in the file because there is none. At least I assume it has nothing to do with that specific file.

Also, I'm on Windows 10 and using Visual Studio Code. Here's vscode environment info:

```js
Version: 1.28.1 (user setup)
Commit: 3368db6750222d319c851f6d90eb619d886e08f5
Date: 2018-10-11T18:13:53.910Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64
```

Comment: Please add your TypeScript version and your package.json file to the question, then hopefully I'll be able to reproduce the problem and find the cause.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I added the info you requested. Sorry for getting back to you so late.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `@types/webgl-ext` package (an indirect dependency of `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu`) contains a declaration of the `getExtension` method of `WebGLRenderingContext` that is incompatible with the declaration of the `getExtension` method of `WebGLRenderingContextBase` in recent versions of the TypeScript standard library.  I'm not sure what should be done about this, so I suggest you first [file an issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues) against `@types/webgl-ext`.  If you don't get an answer there, then you could escalate to TensorFlow.js support resources to ask if the dependency on a broken and apparently unmaintained package can be removed.

In the meantime, a workaround that may work is to create your own dummy version of the `@types/webgl-ext` package that is empty.  Create a directory in your project to hold the dummy package (for example, suppose you name the directory `webgl-ext`), copy the `package.json` from the real `@types/webgl-ext` package, create an empty `index.d.ts` file, and then register the dummy package in your main `package.json` using a relative path:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^0.1.18",
    "@types/webgl-ext": "./webgl-ext"
  },
```

Comment: You can also downgrade typescript. 2.9.2 does not have this issue, but 3.1.3 does.

Comment: @Jakub

I just installed TS 2.9.2 locally and I got these errors: https://hastebin.com/ujapiwiqup.coffeescript

Comment: @xiaodeaux - i'm just beginning to learn typescript, so i don't know why these issues would occur. but you could try re-installing tfjs.

Comment: @Jakub yeah I just gave that a shot. I think what Matt said above is the primary thing to focus on. Figure out how to resolve TFJS using a 3rd party lib that TS seems to implement already now.

Comment: A PR to update webgl-ext has been submitted to DefinitelyTyped. In order for things to work, TFJS will have to move to TS2.7+ and the newer version of the webgl-ext package, which is a breaking change. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29971

Comment: for those following these comments, that PR has been merged. thanks so much @zenmumbler

Answer (score 10):

According *@tafsiri* on [tfjs issue: Compile error with @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4201) the issue is: *"caused by a clash between the now built in types for webgl and the @types/webgl2 package we currently use"*.

He gives the next solution (that worked for me):

- Edit you file `tsconfig.json` and add the option `skipLibCheck`

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      // skip error: Interface 'WebGL2RenderingContext' incorrectly extends interface 'WebGL2RenderingContextBase'.
      // https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4201
      "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    ...
  }
  ```